# Python csv to Nested Json

Tags: python, json

I have a csv available for which I need to create a nested Json. Where a Id has to be root and date in subroot then all the key and values.
I have converted the csv to Json but Iam struggling to get it in required format. I have achieved until here in my code.

```
data = {} 
with open(csvpath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf: 
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)
    for rows in csvReader:
        key = rows['id'] 
        data[key] = rows

with open(jsonpath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf: 
        jsonf.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

data.csv

```
"id","datetime","amount","orders","quantity"
31937,27/11/2020 00:00,55.8,2,2
31937,29/11/2020 00:00,96.9,1,1
26575,27/11/2020 00:00,10.9,1,1
```

output.json

```
{
    "31937": {
        "order_datetime": "27/11/2020 00:00",
        "amount": "55.8",
        "orders": "2",
        "quantity": "2"
    },
    "31937": {
        "order_datetime": "29/11/2020 00:00",
        "amount": "10.9",
        "orders": "1",
        "quantity": "1"
    },
    "29581": {
        "order_datetime": "27/11/2020 00:00",
        "amount": "96.9",
        "orders": "1",
        "quantity": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

output required

```
{
  "31937": {
    "27/11/2020 00:00": {
      "amount": 55.8,
      "orders": 2,
      "quantity": 2
    },
    "29/11/2020 00:00": {
      "amount": 96.9,
      "orders": 1,
      "quantity": 1
    }
  },
  "26575": {
    "27/11/2020 00:00": {
      "amount": 10.9,
      "orders": 1,
      "quantity": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And what's the output from that code? What's the *problem* with it?

Comment: its giving output like this:

```{
    "31937": {
        "datetime": "03/12/2020 00:00",
        "amount": "18.9",
        "orders": "1",
        "quantity": "1"
    },...
```

Comment: So [edit] the question to clarify. How does that compare to what you want?

Comment: I want the datetime field to be the secondary root and then the related key:values. But currently id is the root and then key: values.

Edited with output received and required to compare

Comment: That new format seems *worse*, because now you have a dictionary with only one key and you need to know what the key is to get the value.

Comment: Well thats the problem. I tried to wander around the whole internet, but couldnt found a similar problem and solution. And unfortunately thats the output required.

Comment: The output you're currently getting is exactly what your code asks for. If you want the value to be different to what it currently is, why don't you *do that*, the value you want, instead of just `rows`? This isn't a thing you can search for because it's at once: trivial if you know dictionary basics; and specific to your values. But also it's worth finding out *why* that format is thought to be needed, because it doesn't seem particularly useful.

Comment: _" I tried to wander around the whole internet, but couldnt found a similar problem and solution"_ This is an unbelievably inefficient way to learn programming. Real-life programming problems don't have solutions somewhere on the internet, and you'll hardly learn anything if your strategy is to just copy someone else's answer and try to understand it. You'll be a _much_ better programmer if you take the time to understand the concepts you need to use and develop a solution yourself.

Comment: In this case, compare what you want with what you have. You need each "id" key to have a dict as its value. In this dict, the date should be the key, and value is a dict containing the rest of the fields in the row of your csv. Think about how you would achieve this. It isn't that difficult if you understand how to use dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.groupby(['id'])[['datetime','amount', 'orders', 'quantity']]\
.apply(lambda x: x.set_index('datetime').to_dict(orient='index')).to_dict()
```

---

**Output:**

```
{26575: {'27/11/2020 00:00': {'amount': 10.9, 'orders': 1, 'quantity': 1}},
 31937: {'27/11/2020 00:00': {'amount': 55.8, 'orders': 2, 'quantity': 2},
  '29/11/2020 00:00': {'amount': 96.9, 'orders': 1, 'quantity': 1}}}
```

**Formatted:**

```
{
   26575:{
      "27/11/2020 00:00":{
         "amount":10.9,
         "orders":1,
         "quantity":1
      }
   },
   31937:{
      "27/11/2020 00:00":{
         "amount":55.8,
         "orders":2,
         "quantity":2
      },
      "29/11/2020 00:00":{
         "amount":96.9,
         "orders":1,
         "quantity":1
      }
   }
}
```

**Edit2:**

```
df.groupby(['id'])[['datetime','amount', 'orders', 'quantity']]
```

this will group the dataframe by `id`. This id will be a dict key and the rest of the item I have to convert it into another dictionary with a `datetime` as key.

So after grouping, I will take the rows from `'datetime','amount', 'orders', 'quantity'` and make the `datetime` as a key and rest of them as value. This will be done by using `x.set_index('datetime').to_dict(orient='index')`

The reason for using `orient='index'` is I want to have the result in this form: `{index -> {column -> value}}`

Here my index is datetime so it will be a key and rest of the values such as `'amount', 'orders', 'quantity'` will have this form:

`{ "27/11/2020 00:00" -> { amount -> 55.8, orders -> 1, quantity -> 2 }}`

Comment: That was perfect.
I suppose this is the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html?highlight=to_dict) it is referred from?
But the explanation here, is much accurate than the documentation.